# Is the content of an answer sent to the server before submitting?

Tags: support

Let's imagine the following situation. I start editing a new answer. I copy/paste a piece of code that I then intend to strip from all the sensitive information before the answer is submitted.

However, I do see the preview of my code below the answer. Does that mean that the code has already been sent to the server? Was that connection secure or was the code sent in free text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if the rendering of the preview is done on the server or in the client (I assume the client, based on the response times of updates), but when typing out a post it will periodically send the content to the server and save it as a draft, so that you can leave the page, come back, and continue working on the question/answer you'd started writing.  SE doesn't use https (outside of authentication) so I would fully expect that to be sent over the wire as plain text.

If you have highly sensitive information that you don't want to ever possibly get out, then you should remove it in a local text editor and not in the webpage.

Comment: I *think* even the draft is stored in local storage but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Pekka웃 No, it's server side. Try visiting from another browser or computer. Official doc [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/259867).

Comment: Thanks, that is something to keep in mind then when dealing with sensitive data in the code, e.g. access credentials, especially that it's often test code that is being pasted to the answers, which tends to have this kind of stuff not properly stored.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato For whatever reason, trying to visit from another browser does work for me as a way to show that the draft is saved server-side. (Maybe I have an extension that interferes??) However, if I look at the network request done by the browser, I see requests that send the content of the post over the wire. One of them is for saving the draft.